# Error in selecting many checkboxes in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have created a table from 2 different arrays in `AngularJS` that contain employees name and services and rest of the cells contain `Checkboxes` now I want get the ID's of selected `Checkboxes` that I have created another array in the controller,
but the view allows me to select only one `Checkbox` from many in the row

here is my **Html**

```
<form ng-submit="save()">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Services</strong></td>
            <td ng-repeat="e in PBA">{{e.Name}}</td>
            </td>
        <tr ng-repeat="(index,i) in SOB">
            <td>{{i.Name}}</td>
            <td ng-repeat="e in PBA track by $index">
                <input type="checkbox" name="cb" ng-true-value="{{e.Id}}_{{i.Id}}" ng-model="ids[index]" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

[image: This is the table]

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle or plunker please? It would be easier to help you. I designed a similar table using ng-repeat. Could you try to modify the input (in td) ng-model attribute to: `ng-model="PBA[$index]"`?

Comment: unable to create Fiddle/plunker

Comment: http://mvcscheduler.apphb.com/test#/m5
 you can see demo here

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/U6ofYPIynVlsgNUCunCB?p=info
but not working here

Comment: Thanks but we don't need all of this :) I forked your plunk and reduced it to a minimal state of the problem. Could you add some fake data in scopes to mock what is usually returned by your backend please? [Forked Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q2VlhxXnMUkFopAMkHB3?p=preview)

Comment: @glepretre
http://plnkr.co/edit/2ZkzugOLigYQSfmerSlW?p=info



see here

Comment: is that what you wanted: http://plnkr.co/edit/LALmS5TDIrSXWvF60mL6?p=preview ?

Comment: still not functional try to select all three checkboxes in vertical direction only 1 is selectable and also want the id in ids array

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48074/discussion-between-glepretre-and-mohsin-mustufa)